# Text field one character and automatic change to next text field?Not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a program in which I have four text fields which would take OTP with only one character per text field. When the user enters one character in one text field it should automatically move to next text field. But for some reason, only my first text field is able to perform this action and it goes to third text field rather than second. And the rest of the text field couldn't perform the automatic action of moving from one text field to another. I used text field delegate for purposes of coding. Below given is my code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if (![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
    textField.text = string;
    if ([textField isEqual:self.firstOTP]) {
        [self.secondOTP becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if ([textField isEqual:self.secondOTP]){
        [self.thirdOTP becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if ([textField isEqual:self.thirdOTP]){
        [self.fourthOTP becomeFirstResponder];
    }else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Below given is my code to identify whether one character is entered or not.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if (textField.text.length > 0) {
    textField.text = @"";
}
return YES;
}
```

Can anyone identify the bug .?

Comment: Is the delegate set for all four text fields? And you should change `if ([textField isEqual:self.firstOTP])` to `if (textField == self.firstOTP)` (as well as the other two). You actually want to compare the pointers.

Comment: yea it is set for all textfields.

Comment: currently it is going from first text field to third text field . @rmaddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure the `delegate` is set for all four text fields. Also make sure your outlets are connected properly.

Next, change your use of `isEqual:` to `==`. You actually do want to use `==` here since you want to compare pointers, not see if the two objects are logically equal.

You also have a problem if the user pastes text into the text field. The user can easily enter more than one character.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (string.length > 0) {
        textField.text = [string substringToIndex:1];
        if (textField == self.firstOTP) {
            [self.secondOTP becomeFirstResponder];
        } else if (textField == self.secondOTP) {
            [self.thirdOTP becomeFirstResponder];
        } else if (textField == self.thirdOTP) {
            [self.fourthOTP becomeFirstResponder];
        } else {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The issue still persists. No change. @rmaddy

Comment: Have you verified that `self.secondOTP` really points to the second text field? Use the debugger and see what really happens when you enter a character into the 1st text field. Is the call to `[self.secondOTP becomeFirstResponder];` reached as expected?

Comment: The issue was a silly one. I made an error of assigning seconOTP to ThirdOTP text field. But the copying issue still persists. How to solve that.      @rmaddy

Comment: OK, the 2nd sentence of my answer solved that issue. Now what is the copying issue you just mentioned? There's nothing about that in your question.

Comment: I do not want to allow paste function to be enabled in my textfield.

Comment: Why not? The code in my answer solves that issue. If the user pastes in a bunch of text, only the first character will be put into the text field and then move to the next one.

Comment: @ rmaddy. Thanks Hero!! Worked in just 10 Seconds!!

Answer (score 0):

try this it will help You to going next textfield and coming BAck on delete
i hope this will be helful

```
 -(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{
if (textField == FirstChar) {
    if (textField.text.length==0) {
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        [FirstChar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [SecondChar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
else if (textField == SecondChar) {
    if (textField.text.length==0) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

        [SecondChar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [ThirdChar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
else if (textField == ThirdChar) {
    if (textField.text.length==0) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

        [ThirdChar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [FourthChar becomeFirstResponder];
    }

}


}
```

Comment: 1. You do not need to call `resignFirstResponder` before calling `becomeFirstResponder`. 2. It makes no sense for all of your inner `if` statements to call `resignFirstResponder` on `textfield` and then call `becomeFirstResponder` on the same text field.

Answer (score 0):

Important Thing needs to remember

1) Initially, You have to set delegate of UITextField
2) Make sure the outlet of all the textfield are connected properly.

Let's take an example:

1) Suppose you have taken 4 Text Field say for example firstPin, secondPin, thirdPin, fourthPin
2) Now in delegate function "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" You have to make txtOne becomFirstResponder and other all you have to make resignFirstResponder

Here is the code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField )textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString )string
{    
if (range.length==1)
{
    [textField setText:@""];

    if (textField == firstPin)
    {
        NSLog(@"dumbo");
    }
    else if (textField == secondPin)
    {
        [secondPin resignFirstResponder];
        [firstPin becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == thirdPin)
    {
        [thirdPin resignFirstResponder];
        [secondPin becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == fourthPin)
    {
        [fourthPin resignFirstResponder];
        [thirdPin becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
else
{
    [textField setText:string];

    if (textField == firstPin)
    {
        [firstPin resignFirstResponder];
        [secondPin setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [secondPin becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == secondPin)
    {
        [secondPin resignFirstResponder];
        [thirdPin setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [thirdPin becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == thirdPin)
    {
        [thirdPin resignFirstResponder];
        [fourthPin setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [fourthPin becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == fourthPin)
    {
        [fourthPin resignFirstResponder];
    }


}

return NO;

}
```

This code support both adding a text as well as deleting a text

Comment: This is essentially a copy of my answer. How does this answer provide any additional information? And most of the code you have in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is wrong. There is no reason to call `resignFirstResponder` before calling `becomeFirstResponder`. And why do you check `range.length`? If I select an existing character in the text field and then type a new character, your code will simply clear the text field and then go to the previous text field. That's not right at all. Your code doesn't handle a user pasting in too much text.